# SQL not accepting negative numbers proc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that accepts 5 parameters, and it needs to set the description to an empty string, set the dateadded to the currentdate (I use GETDATE). but what I cannot seem to get working is I need the listprice and discount percent to throw errors when trying to enter a negative number. my code works, but my statements do not come up with errors when I try and enter a negative number.

```
USE MyGuitarShop;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('spInsertProduct') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC spInsertProduct;
GO
CREATE PROC spInsertProduct 
@insCatID int = 0,
@insProdCode varchar(10) = 0,
@insProdName varchar(50) = 0,
@insListPrice money = 0,
@insDisPercent money = 0

AS
IF @insListPrice < 0 
PRINT 'this column does not accept negative numbers';
IF @insDisPercent < 0
PRINT 'this column does not accept negative numbers';

UPDATE Products
SET Description = '', DateAdded = GETDATE();
SELECT CategoryID, ProductCode, ProductName, ListPrice, DiscountPercent
FROM Products

USE MyGuitarShop;
GO

EXEC spInsertProduct
-7,'254-652','Guitar', -300.01, 30.00;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `RAISERROR` along with `RETURN` for error handling here. `RAISERROR` will generate the error message, and the `RETURN` statement will force termination, something like this:

```
IF @insListPrice < 0 
 BEGIN
 RAISERROR(N'List Price cannot be negative',16,1)
 RETURN
END
IF @insDisPercent < 0 
 BEGIN
 RAISERROR(N'Discount percentage cannot be negative',16,1)
 RETURN
END
```